# Particle System - set emitter's mesh via script

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, particle-system

How I can set particle emitting mesh in "Particle System"(Shuriken) component? Searching in google returns me tutorials only for legacy particle system.

**UPD:** @gamedevelopmentgerm answered to my question:

> *If you want to control all aspects of particle system in runtime then you must use legacy particles.*

Comment: You're looking for the "Shape" setting exposed in the editor? To the best of my knowledge that hasn't been exposed in the API yet, but granted, I haven't played with particles in a while.

Comment: @Bart, yes, I'm want to setup "Shape" settings in runtime. If it hasn't API (after 1 year from release)... It's bad.

Comment: I don't know if it will detect changes in the mesh though. Perhaps you could try hooking up a particle system with an empty mesh and see if you can swap that mesh at runtime.

Comment: @Bart, answered in [_this comment_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499739/particle-system-set-emitters-mesh-via-script#comment39862171_25500793)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...

UP1. Oh, I see the comment below. No, you can't change mesh shape from script though once I have seen a workaround for this problem. It was something about setting up an empty mesh as ParticleSystem emission shape an then change the mesh geometry from script.

UP2. Ok, I see further details. If you want to simulate fire propagation then I recommend you to consider [ParticleSystem.Emit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Emit.html) method instead of any emission shape whatsoever. I recommend it because with [ParticleSystem.Emit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Emit.html) you will be able to control emission shape in much more flexible way.

In fact, you may use [ParticleSystem.Emit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Emit.html) to emit particles from different mesh instances as well.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent( typeof( ParticleSystem ) )]
public class CustomParticleSystem : MonoBehaviour 
{
    #region Properties
    public Mesh[] EmissionShapes;
    public float  EmissionShapeSwitchSpeed = 0.5f;
    public float  EmissionRate = 10f;
    #endregion

    float          _shapeIndex = 0f;
    float          _timeToEmission = 0f;
    ParticleSystem _particleSystem;

    float EmissionPeriod { get { return 1f / EmissionRate; } }

    void Awake () 
    {
        _particleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        _particleSystem.emissionRate = 0f;
        _timeToEmission = EmissionPeriod;
    }

    void Start () 
    {   
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        _shapeIndex += EmissionShapeSwitchSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if( _shapeIndex > EmissionShapes.Length-1 ) _shapeIndex -= (EmissionShapes.Length-1);

        _timeToEmission -= Time.deltaTime;
        if( _timeToEmission <= 0f )
        {
            _timeToEmission = EmissionPeriod - _timeToEmission;

            Mesh currentShape = EmissionShapes[(int)_shapeIndex];

            int triangleIndex = Random.Range( 0, currentShape.triangles.Length/3 );

            int vertexIndex0 = currentShape.triangles[triangleIndex*3];
            int vertexIndex1 = currentShape.triangles[triangleIndex*3+1];
            int vertexIndex2 = currentShape.triangles[triangleIndex*3+2];

            Vector3 v0 = currentShape.vertices[vertexIndex0];
            Vector3 v1 = currentShape.vertices[vertexIndex1];
            Vector3 v2 = currentShape.vertices[vertexIndex2];

            Vector3 n0 = currentShape.normals[vertexIndex0];
            Vector3 n1 = currentShape.normals[vertexIndex1];
            Vector3 n2 = currentShape.normals[vertexIndex2];

            float u = Random.Range( 0f, 1f );
            float v = Random.Range( 0f, 1f );
            float w = Random.Range( 0f, 1f );
            float uvw = u+v+w;
            u /= uvw;
            v /= uvw;
            w /= uvw;

            Vector3 randomPosition = v0*u + v1*v + v2*w;
            Vector3 normalAtRandomPosition = n0*u + n1*v + n2*w;

            randomPosition = this.transform.localToWorldMatrix.MultiplyPoint( randomPosition );
            normalAtRandomPosition = this.transform.localToWorldMatrix.MultiplyVector( normalAtRandomPosition );

            _particleSystem.Emit( 
                randomPosition,
                normalAtRandomPosition * _particleSystem.startSpeed, 
                _particleSystem.startSize,
                _particleSystem.startLifetime,
                _particleSystem.startColor
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the mesh emitted as a particle? I think @lewis is looking for the mesh that acts as a particle emitter?

Comment: Yes, @Bart says correct - I need to set mesh as **particle emitter**, for fire propagation simulation (to show burning area).

Comment: @game_development_germ, how I can use [ParticleSystem.Emit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Emit.html) to emit particles from mesh? Parameters **(Vector3 position, Vector3 velocity, float size, float lifetime, Color32 color)** does not contains any mesh settings.

Comment: @lewis, in Emit() you can specify your own point of emission, right? Therefore, you can generate random position on mesh surface in your script, its pretty easy (pick random triangle, then pick random point inside that triangle, then transform that point to world space).

Comment: And you can simulate accurate propagation of fire on arbitraty mesh if you use triangle adjacency. I.e. instead of swapping emission shapes you can define virtual emission shape in script and since it is virtual you can provide it with any dynamic feature (scale, rotate, translate, add new surface et.c.)

Comment: @gamedevelopmentgerm, did you mean: 1) invoke Emit() in points of my mesh (with arbitrary step). In other words, represent mesh as group of points, and invoke Emit() in each point? 2) How can I set advanced settings of emitter _(scale, rotate, translate, add new surface et.c.)_ via code?

Comment: @lewis, in fact you don't have to represent mesh as points. Just try to think outside the box. For example, if you have a triangle, you don't need extra information to emit a particle from a random point of its surface (you can calculate its normal with cross-product of two of its edges and you can pick random point with linear interpolation between its randomly weighted vertices). Now, a mesh is just an array of triangles. You can pick a random index of array as well. Therefore, to emit a particle from mesh surface you don't need to preprocess its data structures, you just need to use them.

Comment: I've added an example. It emits particles from different meshes using one mesh at a time and switching emission shapes by a time.

Comment: @gamedevelopmentgerm, thnx for code example. And, sorry for another question - how I may setup in script advanced ParticleSystem settings, e.g. "Emission", "Shape", "Size over Lifetime", "Rotation over Lifetime" etc?

Comment: Unfortunately, all that you can change from script in Shuriken are public fields of ParticleSystem and ParticleSystemRenderer components. If you want to control all aspects of particle system in runtime then you must use legacy particles.